# Windows - Prevent actual writing to directory

Tags: windows, file-permissions, windows-server-2008-r2, disk-io

I use an application from a 3rd party that writes constantly (about 2k per second - about 80 megs per day) to a log file. I do not believe that the application reads from the log file, I believe that its just there for debugging purposes. This is a Windows 2008 R2 machine and it writes to a subfolder in "Roaming" in the Users directory.

Is there a way in Windows to have it just not write the data (but still return a success message)? I don't want the application to fail, but would love to not have that constant disk activity.

Any easy/clean options?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at the application documentation to see if it has an option to disable logs, or to adjust log level? You should probably contact the developer to see if it's possible.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that, but haven't heard back yet - I'm going to presume its not possible.

Comment: On some other OSes, you could put a pipe on the filesystem in place of the log file, but on Windows the pipe exist in their own namespace, not in the file directory structure.  Try a ramdisk and a reparse point?

Comment: Thanks Ben Voigt, that's a good idea about the ramdisk. I'll try it and see how it goes. I have sufficient amount of RAM and so I could just clear out the older log files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can right click that subfolder in Roaming, go to Properties/Security, click on SYSTEM and modify the permissions there so it Denies SYSTEM Full Control.

However, this is unconfirmed as a solution to this kind of problem. The application may indeed crash.

Comment: It will likely result in a file not found exception and crash the application, or possibly send it into an endless loop.

Comment: Most likely, agreed. However if the developer handled this situation with a try/catch, it might just work.